# Acts_as_votable query - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Within my rails app, i'm using the [acts_as_votable gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) to allow voting on my Post model.

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all posts that the current user has not upvoted or downvoted. **How do I do this?**

This gives me the list of ids of all users that have voted on a particular post. Do I need to run this method on all posts and scan against the current user and map out the results, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
@post.votes_for_ids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User has the following methods available, see the [github doc](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter)

```
@user.find_voted_items

@user.find_up_voted_items
@user.find_liked_items

@user.find_down_voted_items
@user.find_disliked_items
```

So using these methods you could

```
@not_voted_on = Post.where.not(id: @user.find_voted_items.map(&:id))
```

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve all posts that a user has not voted for at all

Comment: @KatieH I've update the answer to resolve my oversight.